# Is there an Edgar Allan Poe Story about a clock tower as per the film, "Twixt"?

Tags: story-identification, edgar-allan-poe

*Twixt* is a 2011 Francis Ford Coppola film about a writer exploring a mysterious mass murder in a small town that boasts an odd clock tower with seven faces, all with different times. One of the plot points is that Edgar Allan Poe slept at the hotel wherein the murders took place, and an in-film newspaper article indicates that Poe wrote a short story based on the town's clock tower. So far, the only Poe story I've found involving a clock tower is "A Predicament", which does not sound quite right for the town, being a primarily humorous piece. Was there a short story as indicated in the course of the film?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The story is [The Devil in the Belfry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Devil_in_the_Belfry).

> Above the session-room of the Council is the steeple, and in the steeple is the belfry,
>   where exists, and has existed time out of mind, the pride and wonder of the village --- the
>   great clock of the borough of Vondervotteimittiss. And this is the object to which the
>   eyes of the old gentlemen are turned who sit in the leather-bottomed arm-chairs.
>
> The great clock has seven faces --- one in each of the seven sides of the steeple --- so
>   that it can be readily seen from all quarters. Its faces are large and white, and its hands
>   heavy and black.

Comment: Hah. Good job. That does indeed sound correct.